# how can access to video path in my device?

Tags: android, kotlin, camera-view

```
 @Throws(IOException::class)
private fun createVideoFile(): File {
    // Create an image file name
    val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
    return File.createTempFile(
        "oogoo_${timeStamp}_",
        ".mp4",
        storageDir
    ).apply {
        videoPath = this.path
        videoUri = this.toUri()
    }
}
```

Iam using CameraView to record Video .
when stop record I get path of record

> D/VideoTaken: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.testgogoapplication/files/Movies/oogoo_20211021_125639_3062139219833544197.mp4
>
> file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.testgogoapplication/files/Movies/oogoo_20211021_125639_3062139219833544197.mp4

put not found this path in Device how can access to this path?.

> 

if there is another way to save the video to storage (best way to  write file) by Kotlin

Comment: Which app did you use to find a file in your apps private dir? On an Android 11+ device other apps like file managers have no acces to the private dir of your app and in general not to  /storage/emulated/0/Android/data.

Comment: If file manager apps should be able to see your file then save to getExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) or use MediaStore.insert() to get an uri for a file in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```kotlin
    private fun createVideoOutputPath(context: Context): String {
        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver

        /** Represent the videos collection */
        val videosCollection: Uri = sdkAndUp(29) { // if sdk is 29 or higher
            MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
        } ?: MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

        /** Represents the data values of the video to be saved */
        val contentValues = ContentValues()

        // Adding the file title to the content values
        contentValues.put(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
            "VID_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4"
        )
        // Adding the file display name to the content values
        contentValues.put(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            "VID_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4"
        )
        /** Represents the uri of the inserted video */
        val videoUri = contentResolver.insert(videosCollection, contentValues)!!
        // Opening a stream on to the content associated with the video content uri
        contentResolver.openOutputStream(videoUri)
        /** Represents the file path of the video uri */
        val outputPath = getUriRealPath(context, videoUri)!!
        // Deleting the video uri to create it later with the actual video
        contentResolver.delete(videoUri, null, null)
        return outputPath
    }

    private fun getUriRealPath(contentResolver: ContentResolver, uri: Uri): String {
        var filePath = ""
        val cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                var columnName = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
                when (uri) {
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI -> {
                        columnName = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
                    }
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI -> {
                        columnName = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA
                    }
                }
                val filePathColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName)
                filePath = cursor.getString(filePathColumnIndex)
            }
            cursor.close()
        }
        return filePath
    }
```

This code inserts a video uri to `MediaStore`, retrieves its file path, and removes it from `MediaStore`. This path will be to the Movies directory which is public and does not require permissions. Now you can use this file path to create a `File` object like so:
`val file = File(createVideoOutputPath(context))`